# Different content for user level in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, members

okay so I'm using the following code to show different content to users with different levels in WordPress

```
    <?php global $user_ID; if( $user_ID ) : ?>
<?php if( current_user_can('level_10') ) : ?>

<a href="http://techyoucation.com/wp-admin/">Admin</a>

<?php else : ?>

FREE

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I get different content to show for users with level 10, level 9, level 8, level 7 ect...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show?  For example a menu with links tailored to user role, or a posts page filtered by user role?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do level based filtering - and it depends on what you want to do exactly, but basically you just need simple conditionals ( `if - else` or `if - then` or `switch` statements )  again - depends on context.

```
if( current_user_can( 'level_10' ) ){
 echo  'A - content for user level 10';
} elseif( current_user_can( 'level_8' ) ) {
 echo  'B - content for user level 8 and above';
} elseif( current_user_can( 'level_6' ) ) {
 echo  'C - content for user level 6 and above';
} // ok for wordpress < 3.0

/*
* Please read my note below regarding user levels to roles conversion
*/
if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){
 echo  'A - content for user level Admin';
} elseif( current_user_can( 'publish_pages' ) ) {
 echo  'B - content for user level Editor and above';
} elseif( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
 echo  'C - content for user level Author and above';
} // ok for wordpress > 3.0
```

which will output totally different content for each user , but also means that user level 10 will NOT SEE the content of level 6.. ( unless you drop the else.. )

```
// when Admin logged
A - content for user level Admin
// when level editor and above logged
B - content for user level Editor and above
// when level author and above logged
C - content for user level Author and above
```

or

```
 if( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ){ // Author
    echo  'A - content for Author and above';

      if( current_user_can( 'publish_pages' ) ){ // Editor 
    echo  'B - Additional content for Editor and above';

           if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){ // Administrator
              echo  'C - Additional content for administrator ';

          }

        }

    }
```

which will ADD output based on user levels - so user 10 see `user 6` content PLUS `user 8` content PLUS  `user 10` content

Put in plain human language example one will show `content for level 10 OR content for level 8 OR ..`  while example 2 will show `content for level 10 AND content for level 8 AND` ..

Like said before - there are many many ways to use it , but it all depends on context .

**Note** : Since wp 3.0 the user_level system was deprecated . you will need to filter by [Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) using the [`user level to role Conversion system`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Level_to_Role_Conversion) ..

```
if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ){} // only if administrator
if( current_user_can( 'editor' ) ){} // only if editor
if( current_user_can( 'author' ) ){} // only if author
if( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ){} // only if contributor
if( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ){} // only if subscriber
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need some extra help. I want the code for showing different text for different user levels E.G Level 10 will see the work admin with link to admin dashboard for easy access. Level 9 will see the text PRO level 8 will see Advance and level 7 will see FREE... So I think I need your first code, but can't get it to work. Is there any change you can edit it to include the `<?PHP ?>` tags so I can just copy and paste it and only need to edit the content and levels. Thanks So much

Comment: @Techyoucation - I am sorry . Since you asked about `user levels` specifically ,I assumed you know what you are asking and that you might use and older version ( yep - some still do ). This system is deprecated now . please read my update and Note .

Comment: Hello, No I'm using the latest version of WP but use a plugin called "restrict content pro" which uses levels... The code first code you supplied does not work, but I could be using it wring as I have no PHP knowledge and found the code online. - Thanks - Aled

Comment: I place the code you sypplid but it only words for level 10, any other level nothing shows?